# How to fetch text after another text in python with different symbols to split?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, data-science

I need to fetch the ID created i.e 1255325456 but I am not able to split it and get this value.
My step

1. Extract the line in which 'ID Created' is written .
2. After fetching , I m splitting it , but unsuccessful .
   I have a log(text file) with student data like

   [Info]   |30| 05:38:37.208 |   12/13 | Class TWELFTH
   [Info]   |31| 05:38:37.210 |   11/14 | SECTION : PHYSICS
   [Info]   |32| 05:38:37.212 |   11/12 | ID created: 1255325456

Comment: Does the log always prints ID created at the end, is it a fixed format ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the log is of fixed format

```
log = "[Info] |30| 05:38:37.208 | 12/13 | Class TWELFTH [Info] |31| 05:38:37.210 | 11/14 | SECTION : PHYSICS [Info] |32| 05:38:37.212 | 11/12 | ID created: 1255325456"

print(log.split("|")[-1].split(":")[-1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If such format is fixed, I would do following:

```py
id = log.split(' ')[-1]
```

Otherwise:

```py
id = log.split("ID created:")[-1]
```